# Installing a my Django app on ec2

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud-hosting

Im in the process of launching a Django app on ec2, but have hit a wall trying to install my code on my AMI instance. This is my situation: I have a bitnami AMI up and running that has Django, apache, Postgresql, and nearly all my dependancies pre installed, and I have my fully functional Django app running on my local machine that I have been testing thus far with the Django Dev server. After quite a bit of googling, the most common methods of installing an app to an ec2 instance seem either using ssh/sftp/scp to drop a tarball in the instance, or creating a repository and importing code from there. If anyone can tell me the method they prefer, and guide me through the process, or provide a link to a good tutorial, it would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: so, you already found lot's of ways to do it and instead of actually doing them, you want someone to guide you step by step? I believe stackoverflow is not for consulting, there are many people who will help you with the right price. If you want help in here, go for it, let us know if you have any concrete issue, detail it and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
tar -pczf yourfile.tar.gz MyProject
scp -i /home/user/.cert/yourcert.pem yourfile.tar.gz user@serveripaddress:/home/user
tar -xvf /home/user/yourfile.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually simply scp -R my whole site directory into /home/bitnami of my AMI. I'm using Apache/NGINX/Django with mod_wsgi. So the directory (for example /home/bitnami/djangosites/) gets referred to based on my mod_wsgi path in my apache cfg file.

In other words, why not just move the whole directory recursively (scp -R) instead of making a tarball etc?

Comment: Thanks Sid, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Directly copy the folder where your project resides may work. However you mention that you  are using a BitNami image, so it is likely that you are using the BitNami Django Stack Amazon image. BitNami also provides a native version of the [BitNami Django Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) so I would suggest that you first try to deploy your application on top of the native installer and see what exact steps you need to follow. For instance you may need to install python dependencies or if you plan to use Apache on production instead of the Django development server you will need to configure Apache to serve your project. I'm a BitNami developer and I mention this because make easier the deployment in different platforms (including ec2) is one of the goal of BitNami and as you are already using it you can take advantage of this.